# Is there a built-in function to get the "ghi" from www.abc.com/def/ghi in the BCL?

Tags: c#, .net, base-class-library

Is there a built-in function to get the `ghi` from `www.abc.com/def/ghi` in the BCL? I know it is dead easy to create a small method that does just that, but I wonder if there is something already that will take care of it for me.

If it could also get me `def` and `abc` that'd be a bonus.

Comment: `string.Split` will do the job.

Comment: Hmm. I tried FileInfo but it didn't help me. I guess the Path class would come in handy here, although it wouldn't get me *abc*.

Comment: @Oded: as stated in the OP I am looking for an ALTERNATIVE to manual string manipulation.

Comment: No, you didn't state anything about string manipulation anywhere. I suggest you read your own question...

Comment: "I know it is dead easy to create a small method that does just that" <- I don't know how would it be possible to do that without string manip, lol!

Comment: Yes. Should one infer from this vague wording that you specifically meant string manipulation? If you want a strongly typed URI class, that's what you should be asking about.

Comment: "Should one infer from this vague wording that you specifically meant string manipulation?" That's correct, sir!

Comment: Well, I don't like to infer. "Assumption is the mother of all f**k-ups".

Comment: Assuming that simple string manipulation is the answer to everything is also the mother of something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass the url to the [Uri class constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6c2z492.aspx) and inspect the [Segments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.segments.aspx) property. Or if the string you have could be invalid you could first try parsing it using the [TryCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6skwte6.aspx) method.

Comment: Thank God at least one person didn't jump to `String.Split`.

Answer (score 0):

for .net just use String.Split

```
myString.Split('/')
```

and take the array-parts you need - I don't think that there is a build in function - it won't be much shorter than this anyway

Comment: as stated in the OP I am looking for an ALTERNATIVE to manual string manipulation.

Comment: I can't find "string manipulation" in there - but as I said - I don't think there is. If you don't like it because of the naming or whatever just add something like this as an extension method to string/uri, whatever. I don't consider this function "manual string manipulation" either but Darin gave you an alternative - but I think the work/code will be much more this way - your choice - but sorry anyhow